# Elasticsearch: Sort on different fields depending on type

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two types in my index (`Event` and `City`) and I'm trying to sort them all together by date. However the date's field name is different for each type:
for the `Event` the value is in the `updated_at` field and for `City` the date is in the `update_at` field in one of the nested objects of its `city_events` nested object array (note the filtering by `region_id`).

I've tried specifying each field in the sort array like this:

```
  "sort": [
    {
      "city_events.updated_at": {
        "order": "desc",
        "nested_path": "city_events",
        "nested_filter": {
          "term": {
            "city_events.region_id": 1
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "updated_at": "desc"
    }
  ]
```

But unfortunately this doesn't mix the two types together. Instead, it first sorts all `Cities` by their nested `city_events.updated_at` field and then appends all `Events` at the bottom sorted by their `updated_at` field. How do I mix and sort the two together?

As an alternative solution I've tried sorting only by the nested `city_events.updated_at` field and specifying `"missing": "updated_at"`, however that threw a `"number_format_exception"` error despite both fields being in the same format:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "number_format_exception",
        "reason": "For input string: \"updated_at\""
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query_fetch",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "events_1461095196252",
        "node": "sYQstSw_SN62ojmXgGjPlg",
        "reason": {
          "type": "number_format_exception",
          "reason": "For input string: \"updated_at\""
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

**UPDATE 1:** Based on [the answer by Andrei Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36736985/1851294) below I've tried developing a groovy script that looped over `city_events` for each `City` document selecting the one with a matching `region_id` and then returning that `city_event`'s `updated_at` value for scoring, but had problems accessing nested fields within the script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36781476/elasticsearch-access-fields-inside-array-of-nested-objects-in-a-groovy-script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `script` based sorting, and you would need your `nested` field to have `include_in_parent: true` to be accessible in the script:

```
    "city_events": {
      "type": "nested",
      "include_in_parent": true, 
      "properties": {
        "updated_at": {
          "type": "date"
        }
      }
    }
```

And the sorting part:

```
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "script": {
        "inline": "if (doc['_type'].value=='Event') return doc['updated_at'].date.getMillis(); else if (doc['_type'].value=='City') return doc['city_events.updated_at'].date.getMillis()",
        "lang": "groovy"
      },
      "order": "desc"
    }
  }
```

---

**LATER EDIT**

Even if I add the `city_events.region_id==1` condition to the Groovy script, that will not feel Elasticsearch, this will be pure Groovy programming and not the power of Elasticsearch.

I've tried other approaches (all in ES 2.3.1):

- `copy_to` from the regular `updated_at` field to a `nested` field inside `Event`, so that a regular `nested` sorting is performed over all types. This didn't work.
- even if `copy_to` would have worked, Elasticsearch wouldn't have matched `"term": {"city_events.region_id": 1}` (as `region_id` doesn't exist in `Event`) from the `sort` part in the `Event` type and for those values would have used `-9223372036854776000` instead of the actual date (that values comes from tests I performed).
- use a `nested` field in `Event` as well and at indexing time, put that `updated_at` in this nested field. This will not work for the same reason as the attempt #2 above: there has to be a `region_id` in `Event` as well so that the `nested` filter from the `sort` part will apply for **both** types.

What I would suggest, as a **proper way of dealing with this, is to re-think a bit the data structure** so that the sorting part (at least) will follow the Elasticsearch way of doing things. Your types are called `City` and `Event` and inside `City` you have a list of (nested) `city_events`. Can't you include `Event` in the `City` and duplicate the events' details in each city? This doesn't have to be a normalized, RDB data structure. On the contrary, ES is happier with non-normalized data.

---

For the completeness sake but **I don't recommend this**:

```
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "script": {
        "inline": "if (doc['_type'].value=='Event') return doc['updated_at'].date.getMillis(); else if (doc['_type'].value=='City') {for(nestedObj in _source.city_events) {if(nestedObj.region_id==1) return nestedObj.updated_at.toLong();}}",
        "lang": "groovy"
      },
      "order": "desc"
    }
  }
```

*Note that I haven't done all the proper checks in the Groovy script above (checking if there are actually nested objects in the document for example).*

Comment: Thanks! Could you also show how to filter on `"city_events.region_id": "$some_id"` via this script since it's an array of records within `city_events` and I only want to use the one with `$some_id` for sorting.

Comment: Thank you! Rethinking the data structure and including a common field (even though it duplicated the data for events) on both types was an obvious solution I can't believe I haven't thought of. I ended up adding a nested `city_events` object on `Events` as well and then sorted both Events and Cities by the `nested_filter` I originally included in the question. Both you and @Sebastian suggested this, but Sebastian was the first, so I'll award the bounty to him. But since your answer is more detailed, I'll mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: Yep, agree with you.

Comment: I have same problem but in my case one of my neste property is String and the other is number how can handle it?

Answer (score 2):

Elasticsearch data should be optimized for reading. The best solution would be adding common field to both types storing the relevant sort value.

Regarding multiple nested objects within the city: I'd still store the most relevant (recent) value at the city level.