# Elasticsearch conditional/nested sorting

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm using ES 1.7.2, here is my mapping:

```
{
   "template":"products*",
   "mappings":{
   "Product":{
     "dynamic":"false",
     "properties":{
        "id":{
           "type":"long"
        },
        "name":{
           "type":"string",
           "analyzer":"standard"
        },
        "score":{
           "type":"double"
        },
        "reviews":{
           "type":"nested",
           "dynamic":"false",
           "properties":{
              "positive":{
                 "type":"nested",
                 "dynamic":"false",
                 "properties":{
                    "reviewCount":{
                       "type":"integer"
                    },
                    "quote":{
                       "type":"string",
                       "analyzer":"standard"
                    },
                    "aspects":{
                       "type":"nested",
                       "dynamic":"false",
                       "properties":{
                          "id":{
                             "type":"long"
                          },
                          "name":{
                             "type":"string",
                             "analyzer":"standard"
                          },
                          "score":{
                             "type":"double"
                          },
                          "frequency":{
                             "type":"integer"
                          }
                       }
                    }
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
   }
}
```

I would like to code a query this will match products that contain specific `reviews.positive.aspects.id` with `score` higher than X, and the results will sorted by that `score` if `reviews.positive.aspects.frequency` is higher than Y otherwise sort by `reviews.positive.aspects.frequency`. I was trying the following, but no good:

```
RangeFilterBuilder productScoreFilter = rangeFilter( "score" ).from( productScore ).includeLower( true );

QueryBuilder productScoreQuery = filteredQuery( matchAllQuery(), andFilter( productScoreFilter ) );

client.prepareSearch( "products" ).
  setQuery( productScoreQuery ).
  setSize( resultsCount ).
  addSort( fieldSort("score").order( SortOrder.DESC).setNestedFilter(rangeFilter("reviews.positive.aspects.frequency").gte("50") ) ).
  setSearchType( SearchType.QUERY_THEN_FETCH ).
  get();
```

But results are not sorted as I wish. From reading around I think I should use script based sorting, but I'm not sure how this is works with nested sorting. Any help is appreciated .

Thanks.

Comment: What if your Product has more positive reviews and, thus, more than one frequency value to compare with? What then?

Comment: Correct, forgot to mention - the reviews is an array. There are also negative reviews, omitted for simplicity.

Comment: You don't get the point: from that array of values which frequency are you going to compare in `reviews.positive.aspects.frequency > Y`?

Comment: Thanks for paying attention :-) I was trying to phrase the question as simple as possible, looks like I omitted too many details.. I updated the question, basically there is another matching criteria - <code>reviews.positive.aspects.id</code>. I omitted the nested query since this works for me, only sorting do me troubles :-(

Comment: I've seen this type of question before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36727898/elasticsearch-sort-on-different-fields-depending-on-type/36736985#36736985. Basically, you need script sorting (for the decision part) and then you need to apply the same nested filter you have in the main query to the script itself so that the sorting happens on the filtered nested values.

Comment: **Or** start using `function_score` to manipulate the score in such a way that fits with your decisional sorting and the values of the frequencies. This idea is to simply sort by score, but the score itself is in such way calculated that it matches your custom conditionals.

Comment: If using function_score, is it possible to reference the value of a nested field, like doc[reviews.positive.aspects.id].value? Can you point me to some resources showing how to achieve that with Java api?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure If this is the only problem but Try setting the nested path also along with the nested filter when you sort. I recently ran it to similar issue when sorting by nesting fields.